# Function generators in for loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop, generator

I'm trying to have a better understanding of how generators work in javascript.

From MDN:

> The function* declaration (function keyword followed by an asterisk)
>   defines a generator function, which returns a Generator object.

```
function *range(from, to) {
    var counter = from;
    while(to >= counter) {
        yield counter
        counter++
    }        
}

for (var r of range(5, 10)) {
    console.log( r );
}

// print: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

I'm not sure how I understand exactly what's happening in the snippet above.

Aren't generators supposed to be called, stored as (generator) objects and then called by the `next()` method. (like below)

```
function *foo () {
      yield 'woo';
 }
 var G = foo();
 console.log( G.next() );
```

In the code above, on line 4 with `var G = foo();` I am **not** calling a function and creating new execution context, this should just return a generator object (and store it under the label `G`).

I'll invoke the actual function `foo`, when I call the `next()` method on it, on line 5. At that point, I'm creating an execution context, executing the code inside `foo` and yielding out the string `"woo"`.

How the first snippet is exactly supposed to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling a generator function will return an iterator (the object with a `.next` function), and a `for..of` loop will *automatically* iterate over iterable objects. While you *can* store the iterator in a variable beforehand:

```
const iter = range(5, 10);
for (var r of iter) {
  ...
}
```

it's not necessary - the `for..of` only needs a single reference to an iterator, after all.

You could imitate this in code by passing a single reference to an iterator into a function that calls each `.next` function until the iterator is exhausted:

```js
function *range(from, to) {
    var counter = from;
    while(to >= counter) {
        yield counter
        counter++
    }        
}

iterate(range(5, 10), num => {
  console.log(num);
});

function iterate(iterator, callback) {
  while (true) {
    const { value, done } = iterator.next();
    if (done) return;
    callback(value);
  }
}
```

As you can see, there's no need to store the iterator in a variable before passing it to `iterate`, just like you can use the `range(5, 10)` call directly to a `for..of` loop, because the loop (or function)'s internals do all the iteration for you.

Comment: isn't the only goal of range(5, 10) return an object? here it looks like it actually runs the *range() function.

Comment: looks like the loop internal implicity make the call the method of range when I would have expected something more like range(5, 10).next().

Comment: Yes, it does run the `*range` generator function, which returns an iterator, and then that iterator can be passed to the `for` loop (or to some other function like `iterate`) which will iterate over the iterator.

Comment: `while (true) {
    const { value, done } = iterator.next();
    if (done) return;
    callback(value);
  }`

makes sense.. so, the logic of this while loop, with the more explicit call to `iterator.next()`, is all masquerade by the `for .. of` loop. Correct?

Comment: Right, the `for..of` loop automatically goes through the iterator, similar to how the `iterate` function goes through the iterator. A manual counting `for (let i = ..` loop wouldn't work in this situation (at least, not very well) because there's no way to tell beforehand how many iterations an iterator will go through before it's finished. May as well use a `while` loop like in the `iterate` function.

Comment: @leonardofed read about the [iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), it has lots of detailed information about this.

Answer (score 1):

So, the short answer to your question is that the [for ... of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) actually only expects an object which conforms to the [Iterable Protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol). This is an object which has a function bound to the symbolic key `Symbol.iterator` that returns an iterable object.

Generators actually have this property **and** the `next` function (which is required for implementations of the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol)). You can see this in the following snippet.

```js
const f = function*() {
  let i = -1; 
  while(true){
        i = i + 1; 
        yield i;
  }
};

const generator = f();
console.log(generator[Symbol.iterator]);
console.log(generator.next);
```

So, this is why you don't need to create an instance of the generator object for the `for...of` loop nor call `next` explicitely. This can be handled automatically due to the contract of the Iterable protocol.

That being said, you can mimic the behavior of the `for...of` loop with a `while` loop by creating the iterator object from the generator object (or calling `next` directly) as follows:

```js
const f = function*() {
  let i = -1; 
  while(true){
        i = i + 1; 
        yield i;
  }
};

const generator = f();
const iterator = generator[Symbol.iterator]();
    
let j = 0;
let next;
while(j < 5) {
      next = iterator.next();
      console.log('next: ', next);
      j = next.value;
}
```

By principle, this is probably also what the native code for the `for...of` loop does.